# Running code after press home button using Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have an app which build on Xcode objective-c, I have a code and I need that code to run even if the user press the home button.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: I am going to run a code that request data using PHP

Comment: If you are making a request during background execution, there's always a chance that your app will be terminated if the request takes too long.  Another option is a background NSURLSession: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1) chapter of the *App Programming Guide for iOS.*

There are three difference scenarios for background network requests:

1. The user initiates a simple request and expect the server to respond reasonably quickly, but want to make sure that if the user leaves the app before the request complete, that it really has a chance to finish gracefully in the background.

   See the [Executing Finite-Length Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3) section of the aforementioned guide for a discussion on how to request a little extra minutes after the user leaves the app, and that may be sufficient to finish the network request.
2. You are requesting large volumes of data (or uploading a lot of data), where it is anticipated to possibly require more than a few minutes to finish, especially on slow connection.

   In this case, as Phillip Mills pointed out, you can use a background `NSURLSession` (as discussed in the [Background Transfer Considerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW44) section of the *URL Loading System Programming Guide: Using NSURLSession* guide.
3. You want to periodically make very quick calls to your web service to check to see if there is any new data, even if the user isn't using your app at the time.

   In this case, you should look into "Background Fetch". See the [Fetching Small Amounts of Content Opportunistically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56) section of the *App Programming Guide for iOS.* You can't control precisely when it checks, but it is a way to initiate short network requests even when the app isn't currently running.

   Note, if this opportunistic background fetch determines that there is a large volume of data to be downloaded, you can combine this pattern with the previous pattern (the background `NSURLSession` I discussed in point #2).

   For more information on this, see the WWDC 2013 video, [What's New with Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=204).